# is it possible to retrieve Facebook user name or id from photo URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml

If i have facebook users photo's URL, for example: https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/885089_523687507674066_732194510_o.png

Can i retrieve user's name or id which own this photo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, fetch the photo_id from the url. For eg:

> **Link**: https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/885089_523687507674066_732194510_o.png
>
> **PhotoId**: 523687507674066

Then make the `\GET` request to this ID. Just like this:

```
\GET http://graph.facebook.com/523687507674066
```

(you can validate [this link](http://graph.facebook.com/523687507674066) in the browser)

You'll get the JSON response just like-

```
....
from: {
  category: "Recreation/sports website",
  name: "Emocje do pełna",
  id: "290868840955935"
},
....
```

So, you just have to fetch the `id` from the `from` paramter

Answer (score 3):

Yep https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=523687507674066 The middle number is the photo id

Comment: I don't think OP is asking for the `photo id`

Comment: Works for photos of friends, not pages etc

Answer (score 1):

Late response on this - sorry.

Taking the middle number from the image file name, you can sometimes find the profile it came from.

www.facebookcreep.com has a tool for this. It takes the number and looks up to see if it can locate the profile. I believe the pictures needs to have been shared to public is the downfall though.